# Extracting words between two expressions

Tags: regex

I want to extract the name between account number and amount while parsing stream of transactions
here is a sample transactions:

```
18-05 12.34.56.789 MAHMOUUD ADAM 100,00 123 18-05-2014
(18-05) Alexandria
```

I have tried the following but it returns null

```
(?<=\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{3})(\w)+(?=\d+,\d+)
```

i.e. look behind for account number || {one or more words} || look ahead for amount

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\w` equals `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` - it does not match spaces. But it does match numbers, so if you just use

```
(?<=\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{3})([\w ]+)(?=\d+,\d+)
```

it willl match `MAHMOUUD ADAM 10`. (only one 0 is taken by the look ahead).

Try this one:

```
(?<=\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{3} )([a-zA-Z ]+)(?= \d+,\d+)
```

(I also added to match the spaces before and after the name to the look-arounds so they are not included in the match).

Comment: You don't need to capture anything - you can remove the brackets ie just have `[a-zA-Z ]+`

Comment: Okay, that'll match _any_ word. Also `Alexandria`. I think the OP wants only specific strings.

Comment: I meant instead of your middle term; still with your look arounds. Literally remove two brackets from your regec

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
\b([A-Z]+(?:\s[A-Z]+)*)\b
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/eL2rK3/2)**

[image]

I've updated the answer to support three names **[Bohemian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256196/bohemian)** suggestion

Comment: What if there are three names, like "John Ian Smith"?

Answer (score 0):

With anchors, character classes, and the m flag:

```
/^(?:[\s\d\-.]+)([a-zA-Z\s]+)\s/m
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eX6dF7/1)

Or, if you want to be more specific:

```
/^(?:\d{2}-\d{2})\s(?:\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{3})\s([a-zA-Z\s]+)\s/m
```

[Demo 2](http://regex101.com/r/eX6dF7/2)